# Error "Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused" While subscribing server sent events channel sseclient in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, server-sent-events, urllib3

I am new to python, I have SSE server on Node

while client is created in Python using sseclient(https://pypi.org/project/sseclient/) i am trying to subscribe to sse channel.
sample code:

```
import json
import logging
import threading
import time
from sseclient import SSEClient

class SSE_Handler(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,url):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.sse_events = SSEClient(url)
        for msg,event in enumerate(self.sse_events,start=1):
            try:                
                if event.event == "SYSTEM_RESTART":
                    print("System restart event")
                    reboot_system()
                    
                elif event.event == "SERVICE_RESTART":
                    print("Service restart event")
                    restart_service()
                
                else:
                    print("Invalid event")
            except Exception as e:
                logging.error(e)
```

if the server is not active or server is stopped
I am getting exception and client stops working:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=81): Max retries exceeded with url: /comm (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0xb5a10df0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
```

I want client to wait for the server to restart or become active without throwing exception.